# How to hide the soft keyboard after hitting the search dialog box

Tags: android

I'm trying to use Android's built-in search dialog, and it's working fine except when I try to use it with a ProgressDialog. The basic chain of events it this:

- User press the search button, enters a query and submits it.
- The SearchManager calls the search Activity's onCreate method.
- In the onCreate method, I call an AsyncTask that runs a query and shows a ProgressDialog in the onPreExecute method and hides it in the onPostExecute method.
- This all happens fine except as soon as I submit the query the screen looks like this:

... which is pretty ugly. How can I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 0):

I dont see the image, but i think it must be the softkeyboard sitting there. It can be removed from the code by calling:

```
 ((InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).hideSoftInputFromWindow(searchField.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

This should be called before the dialog is made and shown.